# Just out of curiosity, is it possible for Node.compareDocumentPosition to return 8+4=12 or 16+2=18?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have seen it return 16+4=20 and 8+2=10, but I don't think 12 and 18 are ever possible at all, but just want to make sure I'm not missing anything so that I can write my wrapper function more simply.

Here is the reference for the api
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition

Comment: The [actual specification of the algorithm](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-comparedocumentposition) could tell you the possible combinations.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, those combinations are not possible based on the algorithm [specs](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-comparedocumentposition)